# Is a compact simplicial complex necessarily finite?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm aware that a finite simplicial complex is compact, and I am wondering whether the converse is true.

If we have the topological realisation of a simplicial complex (not necessarily finite), $|K|$, can we say that this is contained in a union of all it's insides (which are open) and therefore we can find a finite sub cover of this, and so it has a finite number of faces? However I'm slightly concerned that not all the insides are open, because 0-simplices only contain a single point?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this question is yes. This is Proposition A.1 in Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. It's done for CW complexes there but the idea should be exactly the same. The key observation is that infinite simplicial complexes are given the weak topology: is $S^{n}$ is the simplicial complex up to the $n$ dimensional skeleton, then a subset $X$ of $S$ is closed if and only if $X \cap S^{n}$ is closed in each $S^{n}$. This allows you to inductively construct a closed, discrete, infinite sequence of points if $S$ is infinite.

Comment: Note that a simplicial complex is a special case of a CW complex (that's what you've shown), so one can simply apply Proposition A.1 rather than reproving it.

Comment: The space with vertices removed is open.  A tiny neighborhood of each vertex is open.  Can you find a finite sub-cover of this open covering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general fact

> **Lemma:** Let $X$ be the union of its subspaces $X_\alpha$ with the coherent topology, i.e. a subset $K$ is closed if $K\cap X_α$ is closed in $X_α$ for each $α$. Let's say $β<α$ iff $X_β\subset X_α$ Further assume:
>   (a) $X_α\cap X_\beta=X_\gamma$ for some $γ$ depending on $α,β$
>   (b) $\{β\mid β<α\}$ is finite for each $α$
>   (c) Each $X_α$ is $T_1$
>   Define $e_α=X_α-\bigcup_{β<α} X_β$. Then each subset $B$ contains a closed discrete subset $S$ with exactly one point from each $e_α$ met by $B$.
>   **Proof:**
>   Choose one $x_α$ from $e_α\cap B$ whenever possible and let $S$ be the set of all these $x_α$. Note that $X_α\cap e_β\ne\emptyset$ implies $X_β\subseteq X_α$. From this and from (b) it follows that the $e_α$ partition $X$ and also that each $X_α$ contains only a finite number of $e_β$. We conclude that $T\cap X_α$ is closed in $X_α$ for each $T\subseteq S$ and each $α$, thus closed in $X$. Hence $S$ is closed discrete in $X$.

**Corollary:** Under the hypotheses of the lemma, each limit point compact $K⊆X$ is contained in some $X_{α_1}\cup...\cup X_{α_n}$

Now if $X$ is a simplicial complex, we can take the closed simplices as the $X_α$ and see that they satisfy the conditions of the lemma. This implies that a compact subset is contained in finitely many simplices. In particular, a compact simplicial complex is finite.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, unfortunately I am only studying my first course in topology and so there are a lot of words there that I don't yet know!

Comment: Maybe the *limit point compact* is new to you. It means that a space $X$ has no infinite closed discrete subset. If $K$ is compact, then it's also limit point compact, as a closed subset $S$ inherits the compactness, and if it's discrete, then it must be finite by compactness.

Comment: @Wooster: Also, if I should expand the proof a bit, just let me know.